# How to load an html page inside unity3d

Tags: c#, html, unity-game-engine

I've been wondering and searching for ways to load an html page inside my Unity Webplayer Application build by GUITextures(buttons for play/pause, plane/box for displaying content), all I found was how to link an html page and open it in browsers. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: What do you want to achieve by loading a webpage? Is it going to be interactive or are you just projecting its visuals? If you want to load external images and apply them to button textures you can do this with the WWW class.

Comment: I just want to load the content of a specific webpage. Any idea on how to that ?

Answer (score 0):

Unity does not have a HTML renderer as far as I know. On Desktop, iOS and Android you can use plugins to show a webpage, but that happens outside of Unity and you are specific asking about Web player.

The "best" solution I can come up with is to use a server script to screenshot a webpage and then load that image via the WWW class. But that makes it non interactive and you will have to get the correct resolution to make it display correctly in your resolution.

Another way is to parse the html content yourself and rebuild it in Unity but I guess that is not an option here.